# JQuery overwriting this keyword in prototype

Tags: javascript, jquery

JQuery seems to overwrite the `this` keyword of my instance method, when added as an event handler. Why does this happen? Code below:

```
function Foo() {};
Foo.prototype.bark = function() {
    console.log(this);
};

var foo = new Foo();

$("#b").click(foo.bark);
```

Output on click:
`<button id="b" type="button">`

However JQuery does not seem to override the `this` keyword in the code below:

```
$("#b").click(function() { foo.bark(); });
```

Output on click:

```
`Foo { bark=function()}`
```

Comment: I believe it's because in the context that `.bark` is called, `this` references your button.

Comment: This is the expected behaviour. All functions that are assigned as an event listener will have the `this` keyword pointing the the element instance on which the event was fired.

Comment: I don't understand. I thought the `this` keyword is bound to the foo instance of the Foo object. How can JQuery overwrite this?

Comment: We need a canonical answer for these "please explain me `this`" questions. I think I've seen one...

Comment: @BlackSheep this is how javascript functions work. `this` is determined solely by the caller.

Comment: `this` is always bound to the context in which the method was called. `foo.bark()`, the context is `foo`. In `$('#b').click(foo.bark)`, you are passing the function as a callback, which is called with the DOM node as its context.

Comment: @Mathletics I didn't realize that JS had such interesting object behaviour. I was interesting in writing it this way because writing out `function() { i.myFunction(); }` seemed redundant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[From the docs:](http://api.jquery.com/bind/)

> The handler parameter takes a callback function... Within the handler, the keyword `this` refers to the DOM element to which the handler is bound.

Answer (score 5):

This is the expected behaviour. All functions that are assigned as an event listener will have  `this` pointing to the element instance on which the event was fired.

You can overcome this by using an anonymous wrapper function as you handler like:

```
$("#b").click(function() {foo.bark() });
```

Comment: That's odd. I thought that `this` was a pointer/reference to the instance object. How can JQuery overwrite this? Also, I understand that I can get the 'expected' behaviour using this anonymous function, but I can't understand how JQuery overwrites the `this` keyword.

Comment: `this` isn't overwritten. Instead, when you say `elem.onclick = myObj.myfunc`, a reference to `myObj.myFunc` is passed to `elem` to use as the click event handler. `myObj.myFunc` is then used in another context (the `elem`'s). Where `this` points to is defined by the context. `this` is always read-only and the context in which a function is executed will define it.

Answer (score 2):

That is because `click` passes reference to the element to it's handler (*which is bark in your case*)

When you do this :

```
$("#b").click(function(){
  foo.bark();
});
```

You will not be able to use `this` to reference clicked element in `bark()`

Comment: You can use `this` in bark() if you do `$('#b').click(function() { foo.bark.call(foo); });`

Comment: I think this is the opposite of what OP is trying to achieve.

Comment: @Mathletics.. That is kind of explanation as OP asked _Why does this happen_?

Comment: I guess I think your counter example is more confusing than helpful (to the OP), because you're explaining how to do what it already does, instead of how to do what OP is asking. See [Marcell's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17091518/7469) for what I think is a better example.

Answer (score -1):

The solution for your problem is `$.proxy()`. You can read more about it [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/)

Try `$('#b').on('click', $.proxy( foo.bark, this ) )`

Edit : actually the correct call of proxy function is **`$.proxy( foo.bark, foo );`**

Comment: `this` there would not be what the OP is expecting